# F# : Monad operations without computation expressions

Tags: asynchronous, f#, monads

Does F# provide any "standard" set of operators for dealing with monadic (specifically `Async`) operations outside of computation expressions? I'm finding my code ends up littered with a lot of local operator definitions like:

```
let (>>=) a b = async.Bind (a, b)
```

Given how nice the set of operators is for composing pure functions - `<|`, `|>` and `>>` etc - I feel I must be missing something here.

To preempt possible comments - computation expressions are fine for some things, but for pipelining a series of asynchronous operations:

```
async {
    let! a' = a
    let! b' = b a'
    return! c b'
}
```

Doesn't feel as nice as:

```
a >>= b >>= c
```

Comment: I suspect this won't be very usable without higher-kinded types. What happens if you have two monadic types you want to use?

Comment: See http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/ or https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing of that sort available in F# core libs.

I would say those operators are an acquired taste. Not everyone comes into F# from Haskell, and for those of us who don't, this kind of code might not really read as "nice".

What works for me is having "pipeline-friendly" versions of those operations around, as a sort of middle ground between workflows and inline operators:

```
module Async = 
    let bind f a = async.Bind (a, f)
```

Which gives you enough rope to work with monadic types outside workflows while still using the standard set of function composition operators:

```
a
|> Async.bind b
|> Async.bind c
```

For a more Haskell-like experience in F#, [FSharpPlus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The "pipeline friendly" form is a good suggestion.

I'm more interested in finding a terse way of doing this sort of thing in idiomatic F# rather than reproducing the Haskell syntax.